# What are the best practices for mobile apps that require login with social networks?

Tags: oauth, mobile-application

So, building an app with online social login is straightforward, Developing authentication backend, a frontend with authentication interface, and ta da! the app has social login feature.

My concern is that my app will have caching feature to let the users access their data offline. in the meantime my app does require an internet connection to auth the loggedin user token that is stored within the app data. my concern about the practices is what does the big names in mobile apps world do in such cases, i can only think of one condition, allow user to access the stored cached data and once the network status goes to online try to auth the user and reload the data. i'm just feeling i'm missing something. so, What are the best practices for mobile apps that require login with social networks when the network status if offline?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Show the user what is cached, and once they connect to the internet, authenticate them. Depending on the style of app, you may want to upload what they did in the cached state to the server, or you can just clear the cache and reload fresh information from the server.

Ex: Tinder, Snapchat, Facebook

Option 2: Show a loading screen until there is a network connection and login the user then (Not really used anymore, and is really frustrating for users)